# Natural deduction proof (Fitch) - Alternative using disjunction exclusion

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, alternative-proof, natural-deduction

I have to build a fitch proof for the negation introduction rule

[image]

with some constraints: I cannot use ¬¬E, ¬I, RAA (Reductio ad absurdum) and ¬¬I. There is also another constraint saying that I have to use the law of excluded middle (LEM).

There are two tips provided to solve the problem. First of all, I have to use ¬E (or 0I). Second of all, I have to use the disjunction elimination:

[image]

The only way I found how to solve it is the following way:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how to use the disjunction elimination? As my solution doesn't use it?

EDIT 1: Correction in proof

EDIT 2: Thank you so much to @MauroALLEGRANZA for the help. This is what I came up with.

[image]

EDIT 3: Here are the rules I can use: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19WQOPuxyskq2s_eWXvR04sl6qMUG5CKx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: But your proof seems to be: $\dfrac {\lnot \phi}{\phi \vdash 0}$ while the text of the question states the other way round...

Comment: If so, the proof must be shortened to lines 1), 3) and 4).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh, does it impact anything to start with the conclusion? Is it still mathematically valid to do it the other way around?

Comment: Not clear... In your proof above you have proved something different (and the proof is unnecessary complicated). Now the question is: what are you trying to prove ? $\dfrac {\lnot \phi}{\phi \vdash 0}$ or $\dfrac {\phi \vdash 0}{\lnot \phi}$ ?

Comment: The question states: "Give the formal inference of the rule ¬I, using LME [...]". As a beginner in the field, can you prove a premise by the conclusion and a conclusion by a premise, in this case, or is it simply mathematically invalid to do so?

Comment: "A [mathematical proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof) is an inferential argument for a mathematical statement, showing that the stated assumptions logically guarantee the conclusion." This holds also in mathematical logic.

Comment: Thank you very much. See my comment on your answer below.

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful if you list the rules regarding $\lnot$ and $0$ that you are allowed to use: $(\lnot \text E)$, $(0 \text I)$ and $(0 \text E)$

Comment: So what rules *can* you use?

Comment: Also, that second proof is still not a proper proof .. you can't have two assumptions in a subproof ... or at least there is no formal rule I know of that makes any practical use of something like that.... unless you *do* have such a rule?  Again, *we need to know the rules that you an use in order to answer your question*

Comment: I added the rules I can use in the original answer, thank you.

Comment: @Bram28 When you say the second one is not a proper proof, are you talking about the premise 0 and premise phi, line 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Subproofs don;t make more than 1 assumption. Also, you don;t infer lines 2 and 3 from 1 ... they are assumptions, so are not derived from anywhere ... you just need to make sure to discharge them at the end. But since you do that only one at a time, it makes no sense for a subproof to have 2 premises.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

$\fitch{
1. \phi \vdash \bot \qquad \quad Assumption}{
2. \phi \lor \neg \phi \qquad \quad \qquad LEM\\
\fitch{3. \phi \qquad \quad \quad Assumption}
{4. \bot \qquad \vdash \ Elim \ (?) \ 3\\
5. \neg \phi \qquad  \bot \ Elim \ 4\\}\\
6. \phi \vdash \neg \phi \vdash \ Intro \ (?) \ 3-5\\
\fitch{7. \neg \phi \qquad \quad \quad Assumption}
{8. \neg \phi \qquad  Reit \ 6\\}\\
9. \neg \phi \vdash \neg \phi \vdash \ Intro \ (?) \ 6-7\\
10. \neg \phi \qquad \qquad \lor \ Elim \ 2,6,9\\
}$